# No recordTypename or id

Tags: process-builder

```
AND(
$Setup.AB_ConfigFlagsForWorkflowRules__c.AB_PBEventProxyNew__c=TRUE,
[Event].RecordType.DeveloperName='AB_CalendarItem'
)
```

I tried the recordtypeid, still doesn't take effect, i'm having problem when creating an event, which the error says in the process builder The flow failed to access the value for `myVariable_current.RecordType.Id` because it hasn't been set or assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Your code or record, that triggered the **flow**, which in this case looks to be **Event**, doesn't have a `RecordType` assigned to it. If you are the **owner** of the flow, you will get an email with steps and error on your registered email address with the org, which will tell you closely (sometimes exactly) what went wrong. If you are not the owner then **edit** and save to become the owner and re-produce the error to get the details.

Put a check before your code

```
IF ([Event].RecordTypeid <> null,
   AND(
      $Setup.AB_ConfigFlagsForWorkflowRules__c.AB_PBEventProxyNew__c=TRUE,
      [Event].RecordType.DeveloperName='AB_CalendarItem'
   )
, FALSE)
```

Comment: well its is a master record to the record type is null :(